# ReflectionException when installing Magento 2.3.2 on Debian 10.0.0

Tags: magento2, xampp

I am trying to install Magento 2.3.2 (with Sample Data) on Debian 10.0.0 but when I try to run the setup it shows this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not exist in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\\Framewo...') #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(49): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\\Framewo...') #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\\Framewo...') #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...') #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php on line 19
```

Setup:

XAMPP: 7.2.21 
PHP: 7.2.21
OS: Debian 10.0.0

Comment: Have you tried running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply.

I had to run the commands suggested by @where. But first, I needed to give write permission in the folders where my Magento code were.